# 20.04 launcher highlighting

Tags: 20.04

On 16.04 keyboard shortcut Alt+f1 highlights launcher (same as super + t on Windows) then arrow keys left/rieght can go through icons to open hitting enter, see info if hitting menu, selct action from opened list in menu.
This function is not possible on 20.04 ; similar is just super + number 1 to 9 opening corresponding app to the numbered icon.
Any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> opens the Activities Overview. The same is achieved using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and also pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd>.

The shortcut to directly go to the Applications overview is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Once you are there, you can use the arrow keys to move to the different icons, and <kbd>PgUp/PgDn</kbd> to move between the pages.

Once an application icon is highlighted, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to see its context menu.

You could change <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to show the applications overview rather than the activities overview in "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts". Disable the existing binding of "Show activities overview" (under the "System" section) then change the binding for "Show all applications" to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Thank's for the comment. Well, the luncher is here to launch desirsed apps from it, not to search through all the available ones... and  in case mouse stucks, malfunction or not working, Alt + f1 on 16.04 allows that also.